# Controller Web API 2 with actions, using EF

Tags: c#

I have two classes, Student and Subject, with many to many relationship, I added two controllers in type (Controller Web API 2 with actions, using EF) to each class. I have just get student By Id, and i want want to add Get Student By Subject. How can I add this method and how can I configure the route in webApiConfig?

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: This is covered in all tutorials, including those found in ASP.NET Web API's site, eg the [Get Started with ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) tutorial. You only posted the default route of your project, not the controllers.

Comment: In fact, if you select the `Web API 2 Controller with actions, using Entiti Framework` template, the controller and actions will be created for you. *Don't rush* to use it though, understand how things work first. Otherwise you'll stumle when it asks you for the DbContext or the model classes you haven't created yet

Comment: I have already created the classes and the database, and Post, delete, getById work. Now I want to create the method GetStudentBySubject, and configure route.

Comment: You probably don't need to configure a different route. You can add a new action to the existing controller.

Comment: You *don't* need a new route. You need to decide *how* you want to display the data though. Do you want to use a URL that looks like `Subjects/subjectID/Students`? Then you need a `Students(subjedtIdd)` action in `SubjectsController` that returns student data.

Comment: Another option is to use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and specify that you want the `Subjects/subjectID/Students` route to be used for a  `GetStudentsBySubject` method in a more appropriate controller, eg `StudentsController` with `[Route("subjects/{subjectId}/students")] IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentsBySubject(string subjectId){...}`